# How to iterate through multiple file extension without caring about case sensitivity?

Tags: terminal, script, command-line

I've seen various topics on how to iterate through multiple file extensions, but in most cases the list is defined.

example:

```
for file in ${arg}/**/*.{txt,h,py}
do
    ....
done
```

As can be seen, .TXT files would be ignored. And sadly, the guy who answered it says it only works for bash4. Mavericks is using bash 3.x

Any ideas on how it can be done on OS X?

Comment: I advise you to read: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pattern+matching+insensitive and post your question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions :) though admittedly, people tend to use it for anything computer related

Comment: Shell scripting questions related to OS X (including the standard bash version) are on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`:

```
find "$arg" -iname \*.txt -o -iname \*.h -o -iname \*.py|while read f;do :;done
```

Use `IFS= read -r` if the paths can end with spaces or contain backslashes.

Or install bash 4:

```
brew install bash;echo /usr/local/bin/bash|sudo tee -a /etc/shells;chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Then:

```
 shopt -s globstar nocaseglob;for f in "$arg"/**/*.{txt,h,py};do :;done
```

`shopt -s nocaseglob` also works with bash 3.2.